# Ajax Progress bar loading too fast

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I am using ajax Progress bar while uploading files to ec2 server. Here uploading works fine. Progress bar loading too fast. It reached 100% before the full file upload.

I refer similar questions but not found the solutions yet.

My code:

```
function Funname() {        
          
      $.ajax({
        
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
          if(response.success === true) {
              $('.progress').hide();
            }else {
                // error code
              }
        },
        xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
          if (evt.lengthComputable) {           
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
            $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete+'%');
            $('.progress-bar').html(percentComplete+'%'); 
          }
        }, false);
         return xhr;
        }
      });
      return false;
}
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: How big is the file you are uploading? In some cases when the file is too small, the upload is performed even before the  progress event is fired.

Comment: How are you asserting that the file has not been "fully uploaded"?  There's a difference between sending the file to your server (as shown by progress event) and your server passing it to your application (not shown).

Comment: File uploading is working fine. That is okay. But progress event always runs fast. If it is large file, it reached 100% before file upload complete. @freedomn-m

Comment: Yes, that's what your question says (almost word for word...).  I don't disbelieve you.  I'm asking how you are determining that it *hasn't* reached 100% when the event fires.  Remember, the `progress` event is "upload to the server" not "complete the request".

Comment: okay. I understood what you told. But I having one doubt, if I am uploading large files like 250mb how it is fastly uploaded.. atleast it takes some mins right? @freedomn-m

Comment: Try a 20Gb file - 250mb would be less than a 2 seconds on a decent LAN.

Comment: okay. But in my application there is no need of uploading above 5gb files. Is any other solution for this? How can I show progress bar for file uploading? @freedomn-m

Comment: No, it's just to confirm to yourself that the progress bar is working, but it's just jumping to 100% because it is uploading to the server that quickly.   Your processing may take longer - but that's not part of the 'progress' event.

Comment: One possible "hack" solution:  add a small transition (eg 0.2s) to your progress bar, then it will slide to 100% instead of jumping there (here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/z7640sod/).   I suspect your perceived issue though is that it jumps to 100% then sits there; which is why I keep mentioning it's not the *request* time, just the upload time.  Adding too long a transition and it will close/finish before it gets to 100%.

Comment: This is good.. but my percentage always showing 100%.. bar loading slowly after add transition. Why the value not changing? What i am doing wrong? @freedomn-m

Comment: It is 100%.  That's why it shows 100%.